# I want to add a folder to git but it only adds a note that I can't open

Tags: git, github

My github repo is https://github.com/deianp17/google-homepage.git.

I want to add a directory (that has more directories in it) to git. 
I did a "git add ." and then "git commit" and "git push" but it didn't push all the directories. 
Now everytime I use "git commit" to try and do it again I get this:

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   learn_ruby (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit

Comment: what does git status give you ? did you modify the learn_ruby again .....alI I can see is that you pushed one change to lear_ruby .

Answer (score 1):

As [Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik) said above: git does not track directoies. So you can't add empty directories into your repo.

But there is a trick: with each empty directory you want to keep, add an empty file (`.gittrack` or `.keepthis` or any name you like. Just make sure that directory you want to keep has at least one file). Git will track that file and add a directory for you.

Comment: OK now i try to "git push -u origin master " files only but it says  `fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby.git
  Use https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby.git`
and then if i use the second link it says  **"remote: Permission to alexch/learn_ruby.git denied to deianp17.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
"**

Comment: I din't know how you use the second link, but it should be: 
`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby.git` then `git push -u origin master`

If this commend didn't help you, you can create a new question with more details. I thinks.

Answer (score 0):

`git` tracks files, not directories. `git` automatically creates a directory when it starts tracking a file in the directory.

So, you don't need to worry about creating directories with `git`. Just `mkdir` them, `mkdir` any additional subdirectories that are needed, and `git add` the new files in the new directories and subdirectories.

The subsequent commit is going to add the files from the subdirectories into the `git` repository. Subsequently, checking out the repository will recreate the subdirectories, before extracting their contents from the `git` repository.